# tracepoint/syscalls/sys_enter doesn't trigger bpf_trace_printk

Tags: c, bpf, ebpf, tracepoint

**GOAL:** print Hello every time a system call is executed.

**CODE:**

**_kern.c**

```
#include <linux/bpf.h>
#include "bpf_helpers.h"

SEC("tracepoint/syscalls/sys_enter")
int bpf_sys(struct syscalls_enter_open_args *ctx)
{
        char fmt[] = "Hello\n";
        bpf_trace_printk(fmt, sizeof(fmt));     
        return 0;
}
char _license[] SEC("license") = "GPL";
```

**_user.c**

```
#include <linux/bpf.h>
#include "libbpf.h"
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int ac, char **argv)
{
        int prog_fd, fd;
        struct bpf_object *obj;

        if (bpf_prog_load("tracesys_kern.o", BPF_PROG_TYPE_TRACEPOINT,
                          &obj, &prog_fd))
                return 1;

        fd = open("mine_user.c", O_RDONLY);
        close(fd);
        //fork();

        return 0;
}
```

**PROBLEM:** when I run the program it just terminates without print "Hello" also if open system call is invoked.

**QUESTION:** what am I missing? I've tried also sys_enter_open instead of sys_enter

Comment: If you run strace on your program, do you see any failing syscall?

Comment: You did run `cat /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace` or something equivalent to dump the trace, right? The `bpf_trace_printk()` helper does not print to the terminal -- just double-checking you're aware of that.

Comment: I've tried also cat /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace_pipe but I can't read Hello nowhere.
If I use strace the last lines in output are the follow
bpf(BPF_PROG_LOAD, {prog_type=BPF_PROG_TYPE_TRACEPOINT, insn_cnt=12, insns=0x55cbad752050, license="GPL", log_level=0, log_size=0, log_buf=0, kern_version=0, prog_flags=0, ...}, 112) = 3
munmap(0x7fb8ef943000, 16781312)        = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "mine_user.c", O_RDONLY) = 4
close(4)                                = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++

Comment: Looks like your program is loaded, but not attached to the probe. See how `bpf_load.c`, for example, uses libbpf to [load a program](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/samples/bpf/bpf_load.c?h=v5.2#n131) and then [attaches it](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/samples/bpf/bpf_load.c?h=v5.2#n212) to the tracepoint. I think libbpf now also provides [`bpf_program__attach_tracepoint()`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/bpf/bpf-next.git/tree/tools/lib/bpf/libbpf.c?h=v5.3-rc1#n4260) as a simpler way to do this.

Comment: Thanks! So I should first find the bpf_program with  struct *bpf_program prog = bpf_object__find_program_by_title(&obj, "socket") and then call
bpf_program__attach_tracepoint(prog, "syscall", "sys_open"). Where I can find the list of tp_category and tp_name that I can use?

Comment: If you have perf installed, you can run `sudo perf list tracepoint` to get the list of tracepoints you can use.

Comment: @Qeole I think you should make your comment into an answer; it might help other users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for other program types, loading a BPF program takes two steps. First there is the actual load (injecting the program from user space to kernel space, where it passes the verifier), that you performed with `bpf_prog_load()` in your case. Then, the program is to be attached to one of the BPF hooks, here a tracepoint.

In your sample code, your program is loaded, but not attached to the tracepoint just yet. See how `bpf_load.c`, for example, uses libbpf to [load a program](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/samples/bpf/bpf_load.c?h=v5.2#n131) and then [attaches it](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/samples/bpf/bpf_load.c?h=v5.2#n212) to the tracepoint.

I think recent versions of libbpf now provide [`bpf_program__attach_tracepoint()`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/bpf/bpf-next.git/tree/tools/lib/bpf/libbpf.c?h=v5.3-rc1#n4260) as a simpler way to attach the program to the tracepoint.

As pchaigno mentioned, you can list the tracepoints available on your system with `sudo perf list tracepoint` (you may have to install the `perf` utility).

Comment: I've tried to use struct *bpf_program prog = bpf_object__find_program_by_title(obj, "tracepoint/syscalls/sys_enter_open") and then call bpf_program__attach_tracepoint(prog, "syscall", "sys_enter_open") but still the tracing pipe is empty.

Comment: In the strace output I see
bpf(BPF_PROG_LOAD, {prog_type=BPF_PROG_TYPE_TRACEPOINT, 
insn_cnt=12, insns=0x55d6f7803050, license="GPL", log_level=0, log_size=0, log_buf=0, kern_version=0, prog_flags=0, ...}, 112) = 3
munmap(0x7f157d73c000, 16781312)        = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/syscalls/sys_enter_open/id", O_RDONLY) = 4
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
read(4, "609\n", 4096)                  = 4
read(4, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(4)                                = 0

Comment: perf_event_open({type=PERF_TYPE_TRACEPOINT, size=PERF_ATTR_SIZE_VER5, config=609, ...}, -1, 0, -1, PERF_FLAG_FD_CLOEXEC) = 4
ioctl(4, PERF_EVENT_IOC_SET_BPF, 0x3)   = 0
ioctl(4, PERF_EVENT_IOC_ENABLE, 0)      = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "mine_user.c", O_RDONLY) = 5
close(5)                                = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?

Comment: Ok I can answer myself this time (at least once XD): open internally calls openat so I have to use sys_enter_openat instead of sys_enter_open...........